# both through the grid or flex to make the last in a series of unit occupied the whole place?

Tags: css

both through the grid or flex to make the last in a series of unit occupied the whole place?

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
```

```
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

 div{
     border: 1px solid green;
     width: 100px;

    /* margin: 10px 0; */
    background: red;

    &:last-child{
        flex-grow: 1;
        background: blue;
    }
}

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/saneq11/yesq6jhf/

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rbkj26vL/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using flex-grow

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: red;

    &:last-child{
      flex-grow: 1;
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/8edy4pv2/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

You can add a width of 100% to the `:last-child` if you know that it will always take up the entire row. This will also force it to break onto its own row. Moving `flex-grow: 1;` to the divs rather than last-child will make the top row grow dynamically to fit the full width.

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

  div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: red;

    &:last-child{
      width: 100%;
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Starbax You have a width of 100px set for your divs. Do you want them to be dynamic and fit to the page or be fixed? Because with 100px it is a fixed width.

Comment: yes that would be the last in the series was not 100px

Comment: @Starbax That isn't helpful in explaining what you want to happen. Edit your post if you need other criteria to be met.